Removing plastic bits stuck in shower valve?
I'm trying to replace a broken shower cartridge (AFAICT, a Moen 1222). However, removing it was exceedingly difficult and it turns out this is because the very back part of the cartridge actually broke off in the process and is still in the valve body.


From what I can see, I need a way to dislodge the leftover bit (that is encrusted to the valve body; if there's a good way to break down the crud, that would be a start!) and/or to cut/break it into pieces that can be easily removed, without damaging the valve. Any thoughts? (I really don't want to have to tear open the wall!)
(Note: it's somewhat hard to see in the picture, and even in person I can't tell what it is, but there seems to be something stuck to the bottom of the valve body.)

Is there an access panel on the back-side of that wall, for example, inside a closet?

That broken piece is going to be extremely difficult to get out and if you do the bore may be so scarred an new cartridge will never seal properly.  Unfortunately you are probably looking at replacing the entire valve.

@DrMoishePippik, no, accessing either side would require non-trivial demolition.

@GregHill, yes, it's plastic, and your suggestion is exactly what I'm going to try next. (Just got back from buying picks and a stick torch.) Feel free to make that an Answer; I'd upvote it, at least, and if it works, I can accept it.

So... in the end I wound up using a combination of a drill and a chisel. Using a drill bit about the diameter as the width of the ring (and an extension so I could get in there), I carefully removed a plug of material from the ring, doing my best to not drill into the valve. Then I used a chisel to cut the rest of the way through the plastic. After two such cuts, I was able to pry the bits out using a pick. Here is the result:

I then went to town with picks, a toothbrush, a "broom" style (as opposed to "wheel" style) wire brush, a pipe reaming brush, and the chisel from earlier. Also toothpaste (serving as a mild abrasive) and Ajax. The end result isn't perfect, but it's a sight better than I started with:

(The pale blue-green goop is remnants of the toothpaste and/or Ajax.)
A lot of what was stuck on was remnants of the cartridge gaskets. The picks were mostly useful for pulling out loose debris. The wire brushes helped, but I found scraping the sides of the valve with the edge of the chisel to be one of the most effective techniques. (An ideal tool would be a rounded chisel with a radius that fits inside the valve body, but readily available ones have the flat of the edge on the inside of the curve, whereas for this purpose the flat edge needs to be on the outside of the curve. A rotary-tool sized wire wheel would also probably be helpful, but rigid extensions for such are challenging to source.)

Wow. That's stunningly clean. Amazing for an in-wall remanufacture operation!

@GregHill, thanks! (Though, out of the two I took, I purposefully chose the photo that doesn't show that there's still some crud in the very back.  I'm also pretty sure you can see in the one I posted a bit of something that doesn't belong at the very bottom, in front of the bottom outlet. At least it doesn't seem to be leaking, though!)

This may be a long shot, but it sounds like the project is at the point where long shots are all that's left to try.
Focused heat, for example a fine-point flame, might soften that piece of plastic enough that it could be deformed and then removed with a dental pick or similar tool.

I tried this, and I think it's a good idea in principle, but in practice I found that I couldn't get a flame in there without it instantly consuming all the local oxygen and going out. I'd need a device that has its own oxygen supply, and those are somewhat esoteric and expensive for a DIY project like this.
